# Screen rotation problem in viewmodel with dagger-hilt with injection

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-viewmodel, screen-rotation, dagger-hilt

I have a problem with injection dagger into view model.The problem is that **losing form inputs when rotating the screen**.Is the problem in my injection or initialize my view model? Here is my viewmodel;

```
@HiltViewModel
class ProfilIslemViewModel @Inject constructor(application: Application,
                                           private val kullaniciService: KullaniciService,
                                           private val kullaniciDao:KullaniciDao
): AndroidViewModel(application), CoroutineScope {...}
```

And here is my fragment that use this view model;

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class ProfilIslemFragment:Fragment(), ProfilIslemFragmentClickListener {

private val viewModel: ProfilIslemViewModel by viewModels();
...
}
```

Here is the module that injected class;

```
@Module
@InstallIn(SingletonComponent::class)
object KutuphanemAppModule {

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideKutuphanemDatabase
            (@ApplicationContext context:Context) = Room.databaseBuilder(
    context,
    KutuphanemDatabase::class.java,
    KUTUPHANEM_DB_NAME
).build();

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideRetrofit(client: OkHttpClient):Retrofit =
    Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(API_URL)
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
        .build();

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideHttpClient(customSharedPreferences: CustomSharedPreferences):OkHttpClient{
    return OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(object:Interceptor{
        override fun intercept(chain: Interceptor.Chain): Response {
            val request:Request = chain.request().newBuilder().addHeader("Authorization",
                "Bearer "+customSharedPreferences.getStringFromSharedPreferences(APP_TOKEN_KEY).trim()).build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    }).build();
}

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideParametreDao(database: KutuphanemDatabase) = database.getParametreDao();

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideParametreApi(retrofit: Retrofit):IParametreService = retrofit.create(IParametreService::class.java);

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideKullaniciApi(retrofit: Retrofit):KullaniciService = retrofit.create(KullaniciService::class.java);

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideKitapApi(retrofit: Retrofit):IKitapService = retrofit.create(IKitapService::class.java);

@Singleton
@Provides
fun provideKullaniciDao(database: KutuphanemDatabase) = database.getKullaniciDao();

}
```

When I rotate the screen the inputs are losing. How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you talking about views losing their state? If so then your view model isn't relevant (at least with the code you've provided).

Comment: Yes , it is relevant with losing state.I think it caused by initialize view model. I edited the question with adding module.

Comment: You haven't mentioned what exactly you're losing? I'm not sure what your Retrofit dependency etc has to do with it?

Comment: I am losing form data. Firstly the form is filling by service. Then I am changing a date.Last when I rotate the screen , data is again default value that come from service.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. It is not relevant my view model or injections. It caused by two way databinding. But even so I put this line into the contructor of viewmodel;

```
 private val savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle
```

I am controlling the state with this param.So my inputs are not losing.